# Switch between threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Im trying to make a code that does this:

INPUT 1:

```
2
123
abc
```

Output:

```
1a2b3c
```

First line is the number of lines below and the number of threads i must use (max 10).
The lines of random characters may have different sizes.

INPUT 2:

```
5
abcdef
123456789
xyz
ghi
j
```

OUTPUT 2:

```
a1xgjb2yhc3zid4e5f6789
```

I'm trying to use mutexes but I couldn't solve it so far. 
Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int n_strings;
char chars[10][100];
char output[1000];
pthread_t thread[10];
int count = 0;

static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INICIALIZER;

void* mix_it_up(void* arg)
{
    char* a = (char*) arg;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        output[count++] = a[i];
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
scanf("%d", &n_strings);

for (int i = 0; i < n_strings; i++)
{
    scanf("%s", chars[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < n_strings; i++)
{
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, mix_it_up, (void*) chars[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < n_strings; ++i)
{
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
}

pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
printf("%s\n", output);
return(0);
}
```

Any help is apreciated. Thank you

Comment: A mutex only ensures exclusive access.  It doesn't guarantee that the threads will run in any specific order.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.   Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: Do you need to use threads?  It not it would be a lot easier with nested for loops.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", chars[i]);` and similar statements  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: those functions return the number of successful 'input format conversions.  In the current code any returned value other than 1 indicate an error occurred.  2) when using `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoid a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to your global mutex, have a global condition variable:

```
static pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

And an additional variable to indicate which thread's turn it is:

```
static int running_thread = 0;
```

Each thread needs to know which sequence id it has. Instead of passing an element from chars, just pass the index

```
for (int i = 0; i < n_strings; i++)
{
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, mix_it_up, (void*)i);
}
```

Then your thread needs to be in a loop waiting to obtain access. Then it passes control by updating `running_thread` and signaling all threads to wake up out of their wait loop to see if its their turn.

```
void* mix_it_up(void* arg)
{
    int threadid = (int)arg;

    char* a = chars[threadid];

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        // wait for our turn
        while (running_thread != threadid)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex); // releases locks and waits for notify
            // mutex lock is implicitly re-acquired when cond_wait returns
        }

        output[count++] = a[i];

        // indicate which thread runs next
        running_thread = (running_thread + 1) % n_strings;

        // notify other threads to wakeup from pthread_cond_wait
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

One downside of this approach is that there will be always N-2 threads waking up needlessly with each `pthread_cond_broadcast` call. That's perfectly fine for ~10 threads.  But if you had hundreds of threads, that's a lot more overhead for each thread to wakeup, acquire the mutex again, run, check if `(running_thread != threadid)` and then go back to waiting.

A more complex approach would be to have N `pthread_cond_t` instead of just 1 shared by all threads. They way, each thread could be explicitly woken up instead of notifying all threads to wake up.   If you had more than way more than 10 threads, this wouldn't be a bad approach. Just remember that you'd still need to check for `(running_thread != threadid)` on each (spurious) wake up. In other words, a semaphore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Had to change a value from int to long but it kinda works now. kinda because it is in an infinite cicle if all the inputs are not the exact same size. Do you Know how to fix that?

Comment: I also have the option to use semaphores, I just thought it would be easier to use mutexers. If you wouldn't mind showing me how to use them properly

Comment: Ahhh... so here's a bug that you need to fix.  Let's say there was just two threads.  The first thread is dealing with a string of length 1.  The other string is dealing with a length of 10 (for example).  Thread0 would get in first, then update `thread_running` to 1 and do a cond_broadcast to wake up Thread1.  Thread0 will then exit.  Thread1 will then do its thing to append to the output and then toggle `thread_running` back to zero and invoke a cond_broadcast to wake up... OOPS!

Comment: Thread0 isn't around to do anything, so `thread_running` is stuck at being 0 and no one around to increment it.  Meanwhile Thread1 is blocked on a cond_wait call.

Comment: My advice would be to sustain all threads to keep running until the thread with the longest input stream signals an exit condition.  If a thread with no work wakes up with `thread_running==threadid`, it's still responsible to increment `thread_running` and go back to waiting.  You could have a global variable set by the "long thread" to signal "time to exit".